# What will happen to Ubuntu GNOME flavour users after Gnome becomes the new official flavour in 17.10?

Tags: unity, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 for the moment and I am asking myself if – through the future upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10 – my Ubuntu GNOME will be exactly the same as the official main flavor, since it will adopt GNOME again, or if there will be two different flavors with GNOME.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The future of Ubuntu GNOME](https://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-released/) according to the developers:

> As announced last week by Ubuntu founder Mark Shuttleworth, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS will include GNOME instead of Unity. Specifically, it will be GNOME (including gnome-shell) with minimal Ubuntu customization. Next year, if you are using either Ubuntu 16.04 LTS or Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS, you will be prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. For normal release users, this upgrade should happen with the release of 17.10.

Looks like there would be a separate Ubuntu GNOME 17.10 image. In the daily builds there is [one](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/daily-live/pending/HEADER.html).

#### Update

It's now written

> The latest Long Term Support release is Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.3.
>
> The **final** stable non-LTS release is Ubuntu GNOME 17.04.

(emphasis mine) on [Ubuntu GNOME's homepage](https://ubuntugnome.org/). Also the daily build linked above is gone. Probably the developers decided not to go on with a separate Ubuntu GNOME 17.10 and pulled out the daily build.

Comment: The daily build's gone.